# Redis/Haproxy issue

Tags: php, session, redis, haproxy

We just switched our one of our php project to use Redis/Haproxy as solution for storing session. The issue we are facing is once in one or two months, the project will randomly lost session. We have to refresh the same page 10~30 times to see that issue. If we restart Haproxy, it seems working again. But, we don't want our client to experience same issue every couple weeks. Is there any thing I should pay attention to?

Comment: You need to provide more details about how you're doing this. If you're using haproxy to load balance or fail over between multiple redis servers, then the problem would happen if it switches to a different redis -- all the data that was saved in the first server won't be there.

Comment: I am not a system engineer, but I will try my best to describe it.
We basically have Haproxy installed locally on all web servers. 

In the application itself, we are calling localhost tcp://127.0.0.1:6379 to to get/store redis session.
The HAProxy is configured to three rediscust servers below..

ex. 
rediscustb01.domain.com
rediscustb02.domain.com
rediscustb03.domain.com

So, in case the first redis cluster failed, it can fall on second cluster.
If the second one failed, it can fall on third cluster. 
That's basically how our architecture is layout.

Comment: Do the Redis servers automatically replicate their data? If not, when you fail over you'll go to a server that doesn't have all the data and sessions will be lost.

Comment: [sf] would be a better place to ask for assistance on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.